# Как считывать с файла по 1 строчке сверху до конца файла в переменную?

Tags: файлы, php

Как считывать с файла по 1 строчке сверху до конца файла в переменную, которую потом проверять на совпадение с другой переменной?

Comment: если я правльно понял задачу - лучше никак( всмысле такого лучше не делать вообще )

Comment: А как сделать так, что бы из файла можно было бы сравнить переменные со строчками из файла?  
То есть у меня есть файл со строчками и есть переменная. Если переменная равна какой-нибудь строчке из файла, то тогда что-нибудь делается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сразу таки не правильно понял вопрос, как я понимаю сейчас - что-то в таком духе:

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$lines = explode("\n", $file); // разбиваем "файл" по символу новой строки
$linesTotal = count($lines);
$yourVarToTest = 'Some text example'; // текст с которым сравниваешь
for($i=0;$i<$linesTotal;$i++) {
    // пройдемся циклом и проверим все строчки
    if($lines[$i] == $yourVarToTest ) {
       // если искомый текст = какой-то из строчек
       // тут твой код :)
    }
}
```

Comment: Call to undefined function file_get_constents()

Comment: Откуда вы такое скопировали? О_о

Comment: После выполнения скрипта выскочила такая «задница». :)

Comment: @Nikita_Rabykin - веселый вы товарищь однако...

Да я опечатался еще вчера, вы в тупую скопировали весь код и пишите о какой-то заднице... Неужели непонятно что надо не `file_get_constents` а `file_get_contents`.

Вообще меня всегда поражали люди вроде вас, такое ощущение что вы мне за этот кусочек кода деньги заплатили - а он не работает xD

Comment: По поводу построчного чтения - вбиваем в гугл `php fgets` и разбираемся, у меня желания вам помогать больше нет никакого :)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, в любом случае:)
На счёт fget. Я так пробовал, но почему то выдавало ошибку что failed to open stream: No such file or directory in :(

Comment: Если выдавало такую ошибку значит ваша проблема была в пути переданном функции. No such file or directory - нет такого файла или директории, т.е. необходимо было всего навсего поправить путь ;)

Comment: >меня всегда поражали люди вроде вас
Да, школяры всем не нравятся

Answer (score 1):

Я вот удивлен, что никто не вспомнил про функцию file(), которая возвращает массив, элементы которого - это отдельная строка файла.

```
foreach(file('file.txt') as $key=>$val){
if($val == 'эталон'){
    echo 'Совпало';
}else{
    echo 'Не совпало';
}
}
```

UPD:

```
$file = new SplFileObject('file.csv');
foreach($file as $line) {
    echo $line;
}
```

Comment: Пусть автор поста уже сам спасается от прочих проблем.

Comment: тут я с вами солидарен :)

Comment: Кстати - @Arni ваш код работать не будет ;)

Функция file возвращает строки, но символы окончания строки не удаляются, поэтому что-бы работало надо сделать как-то так:

      if(str_replace("\n",'', $val) == 'эталон'){
          echo 'Совпало';
      }
      else{
         echo 'Не совпало';
      }

Comment: > `if(str_replace("\n",'', $val) == 'эталон'){`

[trim()](http://php.net/trim)

Comment: не для общего случая, а если искомая строк заканчивается символом пробела или табуляции?

о **trim** я знаю, "спс" :D

Comment: > а если искомая строк заканчивается символом пробела или табуляции?

Для этого у функции есть второй параметр. А вот перелапачивать всю строку в поисках символа, который может встретиться только в конце строки - несамое разумное решение :)

Comment: Ребята, я этот код даже не пытался запустить. Набрал его за 5 секунд и все дела. Я просто просто хотел показать что explode тут был не очень удачным. )))

Comment: про второй параметр trim - не знал, спс.

А по поводу более удачного - не совсем согласен, 100% "внутри" функции file - тоже делается explode

Answer (score 1):

Вообще для больших фалов советую использовать

```
fgets();
```